# Strange Double int addition error with compound assignment operator

Tags: java, precision

For a simple addition as follows -

```
public class TestAddition {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Double a = 1.4278175434624698E9;
        Double b = 0.0;
        int c = 0;
        c += a;
        c += b;
        System.out.println("Sum is " + c);
    }

}
```

I am getting output as 
Sum is 1427817543

If i am using Integer , instead of int , its neatly throwing an error ,but for this , its not giving an error and is producing this output.
Is this a java bug ?

Comment: What makes you think that it should throw an error?

Comment: And what value do you expect? And why?

Comment: Why should it throw an error?

Comment: 1.4278175434624698E9 == 1427817543.4624698

Comment: oh ok , so its expected ... my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you confused about the [unboxing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)?

> From type `Integer` to type `int`
>
> From type `Double` to type `double`
>
> If `r` is a reference of type `Integer`, then unboxing conversion converts `r` into `r.intValue()`
>
> If `r` is a reference of type `Double`, then unboxing conversion converts `r` into `r.doubleValue()`

And [compound assignment operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)?

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent
>   to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1`
>   is evaluated only once.

So this

```
c += a;
```

becomes

```
c = (int) (c + a);
```

in which case we have addition and the operands are [promoted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.

So `a` becomes

```
a.doubleValue();
```

The whole expression becomes

```
c = (int) ((double) c + a.doubleValue()
```

Now, this wouldn't work if `c` was an `Integer` because the expression would be

```
c = (Integer) (c + b);
```

in which case `c + b` is addition and the same promotion rules as before apply.

```
c = (Integer) ((double) c.intValue() + a.doubleValue());
```

but the `double` value result of the addition cannot be cast to an `Integer`, so it fails. Basically, don't use the compound assignment operator with wrapper (boxed) types.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error. You are assigning value to `int` so anything after the decimal point is ignored.

```
1.4278175434624698E9
```

is the same as:

```
1427817543.4624698
```

so becomes:

```
1427817543
```

when you assign it to `int`

Comment: Agreed. There is no problem here

Comment: While this is true it doesn't explain why it will not work if OP will use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: I am wondering if the OP was simply declaring the variable as an Integer but was not using the intValue() method when calculating or displaying the result of the calculation

Answer (score 1):

The value is correct since an int cannot contain decimals.

When you do c+= b, b is first converted to integer, since int and double are convertible types. Integer and double are not convertible, and you get an error.

Note that you should always use BigDecimal for calculating decimal values in Java, else you might get some strange results.